# go mongodb FindOneAndUpdate several fields

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to update several fields without doing the command several times in mongodb using Go and the "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver" driver. Currently doing:

```
        singleResult := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, bson.M{"mid": MID}, bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{eval: 1}})
        singleResult = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, bson.M{"mid": MID}, bson.M{"$push": bson.M{eval + "uids": UID}})
```

I tried several things such as doing an array of primitive.D or a bson.D. I think I'm not really understanding how it works. I also tried using `Collection.Aggregation()` but did not quite get it to work. I assume this should be easy and I might be going over some concept.

**tl;dr: How to send an array of updates to `FindOneAndUpdate` function from `mongo-driver` on Golang** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update = bson.M{
  "$inc": bson.M{"eval": 1},
  "$push": bson.M{"uids": UID}
}

singleResult := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, bson.M{"mid": MID}, update)
```

Comment: Oh, I think I was doing something like `bson.M{bson.M{
  "$inc": bson.M{"eval": 1}},bson.M{
  "$push": bson.M{"uids": UID}}
}` ... Thanks that works. Btw, eval was actually a variable  and the 2nd update was a string concatenation.